# Neo4j using index when it is being updated

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I have a created index like this :

```
CREATE INDEX ON :ResultSet(file_id)
```

With this index, in place, I am populating data from multiple files, lets say, file1, file2, file3. Each of this file will create ResultSet Nodes in neo4j. Parallely, I am running retrieval query

```
MATCH (n:ResultSet) where n.file_id='file1' RETURN COUNT(N)
```

Basically, I am running retrieval query for one file1, when the index is being updated for other files in background. Does Neo4j still uses indexes in this scenario? How can I confirm and measure this? Is there any performance impact in doing parallel retrieval and update on Neo4j index.

Answer (score 0):

This is a safe operation in all databases. Indexes are just additional internal tables that are also sorted. When updating an index, the db will put a write lock on it. When using the index, it will put a read lock on it. Obviously, trying to do both rapidly will have worse performance, but that is one of the prices you pay for lightning fast read queries. If the performance write costs exceeds the read gains, than that means this data probably shouldn't be indexed.

---

TLDR;

Index updates have the same data read/write protection as any other data transaction. They also trade write speed for read speed.

Comment: Can you provide any reference link from neo4j to confirm your points

Comment: @Fayaz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_locking <= I don't think Neo4j specifies HOW it maintains data integrity in the docs, and the source would be hard to understand, but really this is a general DB concept that applies to all types of DB. And it makes since. After all, if simultaneous read+write of an index was not a safe action, it would completely defeat the point of an index in a production environment. Especially one with high volume update needs. =P No matter the actual method used, the general concept is the same.